# Does Accurev expose Rest API like other DevOps tools like GIT, JIRA, Jenkins?

Tags: rest, api, version-control, accurev

I am trying to look for the rest api's to call the various functionalites of Accurev via my custom web application. eg: Rest API to list recent commits in a stream.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you will use the AccuRev CLI to extract the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for yur valuable response !!  Can you please share any pointers how to connect to Accurev CLI using Java code and then run some set of commands.
For instance, I want to capture user specific commits based on the stream name for a particular timestamp. I would use the below command for the same 
accurev hist -fx -a -k promote -s <stream> -t "2018/08/06 00:00:00"-"2018/08/06 23:59:59"
Can you pls guide about the prerequisites needed at the java end for establishing the connection & capturing this info.

Comment: I never used Java when creating scripts, mostly Perl.  As for a connection, you just need to have AccuRev installed and logged in as a user.  When logging in, use the -n option for non expiring session.  Once logged in, you can execute the accurev commands needed to extract the information.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of what programming language you're using, the pattern for interacting with Accuev from other applications is the same.

1. Programatically execute the Accurev command via a shell/command prompt.
2. Either capture standard output or pipe the output of the command to a file.
3. Read the output and parse to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Accurev has a Java library.
Sadly, there are no examples of how to use it. Currently trying to figure it out myself.

https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-accurev/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/maven/scm/provider/accurev/AccuRev.html